# mostrar por pantalla el valor seleccionado de un checkbox

Tags: php, html

Quiero mostrar en pantalla un valor seleccionado de un checkbox una vez enviado un formulario.

```
HTML: 



<html>
    <body bgcolor="silver">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    <h2>Formulario:</h2>
    <h2>
    <form action="formpost.php" method="POST">
        Nombre:<br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
        Contraseña:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        Edad:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Edad"><br><br>
        Educacion:<br>
        <select name="educacion">
            <option value="sin-estudios">Sin estudios</option>
            <option value="Educación-Basica">Educación Basica</option>
            <option value="educacion-Media">Educación Media</option>
            <option value="formacion-profesional">Formación profesional</option>
            <option value="universidad">Universidad</option>
        </select> <br><br>
        Nacionalidad:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="nacionalidad" value="Chilena">Chilena</input>
        <input type="radio" name="nacionalidad" value="otra">Otra</input>
    <input type="text" name="nacionalidad">
        <br><br>

        Idiomas:<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="idiomas[]" value="español">Español</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="idiomas[]" value="inglés">Inglés</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="idiomas[]" value="francés">Francés</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="idiomas[]" value="aleman">Alemán</input><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Codigo PHP**

```
 <?php echo $_POST["nombre"]; ?><br>

    Tu E-mail es: 
        <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br>
        Tu Contraseña es: 
         <?php echo $_POST["password"]; ?><br>

     Edad: 

     <?php echo $_POST["Edad"]; ?><br>

    Estado Academico:

    <?php echo $_POST["educacion"]; ?><br>

     <?php echo $_POST["nacionalidad"]; ?><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías recorres el array de los checkbox para saber cual de ellos se a seleccionado y luego mostrarlo por pantalla. Seria así:

Preguntas si existe algún checkbox marcado con la función de php `isset()` y luego lo recorres con un `foreach`

```
echo "Idiomas: <br>";

if(isset($_POST["idiomas"])){
    foreach($_POST["idiomas"] as $idiomas){
        echo $idiomas;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder ver los valores de un checkbox de forma multiples en nesesario crear una matriz y recorrerla con un `forearch`.
en los casos de los `forearch` hay que verificar si esta seteado el checkbox con la funcion `isset` y tambien verificamos si idiomas es un array con la funcion `is_array()`

Aquí hay una pequeña muestra según lo solicitado:

```
if(isset($_POST['idiomas']) && is_array($_POST['idiomas'])){
foreach($_POST['idiomas'] as $idiomas) {
echo $idiomas."<br>";  // hacemos un echo a los valores debueltos en el array de idiomas por checkbox
}
}
```

siempre es recomendable hacer un **`var_dump()`** cuado se realiza una llamada POST, de esa manera revisas los valores enviados.

[funcion var_dump](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)

[Funcion forearch](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Espero que te sea de utilidad.